# How do you send a POST request in Puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome, http, https, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I use this code for sending a GET request:

```
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.example.com/search');
    const data = await page.content();
    browser.close();
    res.send(data);
})();
```

How do I send a POST request?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Getting the "order" right can be a bit of a challenge. Documentation doesn't have that many examples... there are some juicy items in the repository in the example folder that you should definitely take a look at.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/tree/main/examples

Here is the example; place the following into an async block:

```js
// Create browser instance, and give it a first tab
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

// Allows you to intercept a request; must appear before
// your first page.goto()
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

// Request intercept handler... will be triggered with 
// each page.goto() statement
page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {

    // Here, is where you change the request method and 
    // add your post data
    var data = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'postData': 'paramFoo=valueBar&paramThis=valueThat'
    };

    // Request modified... finish sending! 
    interceptedRequest.continue(data);
});

// Navigate, trigger the intercept, and resolve the response
const response = await page.goto('https://www.example.com/search');     
const responseBody = await response.text();
console.log(responseBody);

// Close the browser - done! 
await browser.close();
```

Comment: Is there anyway i can start the setRequestInterception(true) only on the last request? I'm trying to find a way to send my crawled data

Comment: Can you check if this still works, I copied directly from your answer and from the documentation but it is not working.

Comment: @JBis did you maybe upgrade puppeteer without upgrading Chrome? Puppeteer 1.15 requires Chrome v75+, source: [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4442#issuecomment-496229386)

Comment: Is it possible to make request data different for each url?

Comment: I had to add the `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` header from [Dmitry Sheiko's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59173601/770938) for this to work.

Comment: You might also want to use `.once` rather than `.on` so the handler is removed after you send it. Ditto for `page.setRequestInterception(false);` after the request is sent.

Answer (score 21):

There's a quirk with the way `setRequestInterception` and the `'request'` event work. Once activated, Puppeteer will send the POST data to every resource on the page, not just the original requested page. I was having the issue that all of my page resources (scripts, CSS) were failing to load once I added POST data in Puppeteer.

Since I only want to apply POST data to the first request, this code worked for me:

```js
// Used for serializing POST parameters from an object
const querystring = require('querystring');

// ...

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

let postData = {a: 1, b: 2};

await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.once('request', request => {
    var data = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'postData': querystring.stringify(postData),
        'headers': {
            ...request.headers(),
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
    };

    request.continue(data);

    // Immediately disable setRequestInterception, or all other requests will hang
    page.setRequestInterception(false);
});

const response = await page.goto('https://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: Wishing I had scrolled down about 5 hours ago. I found the disabling of request interception absolutely  critical where I'm using puppeteer to make dynamic PDFs in an Express app. That one line was all I needed to move on!

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [Page.evaluate() method](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluate/) to run [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) inside the browser. For example:

```js
const postResponse = await page.evaluate( async (param1, param2, param3) => {
  const response = await fetch("https://www.example.com/add", {
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    "body": `param1=${param1}&param2=${param2}&param3=${param3}`,
    "method": "POST"
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}, param1, param2, param3);
```

Answer (score 10):

Here the complete example with Puppeteer 2.0.0 :

```js
    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
    const devices = require("puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors");

    async function main() {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ["--enable-features=NetworkService", "--no-sandbox"],
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      await page.setRequestInterception(true);

      page.once("request", interceptedRequest => {
        interceptedRequest.continue({
          method: "POST",
          postData: "foo=FOO&bar=BAR",
          headers: {
            ...interceptedRequest.headers(),
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          }
        });
      });

      const response = await page.goto("https://postman-echo.com/post");

      console.log({
        url: response.url(),
        statusCode: response.status(),
        body: await response.text()
      });

      await browser.close();
    }

    main();
```

Note that if you check `response.request().method()` it won't be updated (still GET)

Comment: My lint complains about `const devices` being defined and never used when pasting this sample. Then, I can't run it because `Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors'`.