# Unexpected result from post request in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I know this already been covered in another question:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060534/how-do-post-request-in-puppeteer). but for some reason, I do something wrong.

I'm having trouble with post request from server I need data of.
 [here](https://www.shufersal.co.il/pages/homepage.aspx)

If I write the following post request directly from the website's console (using ctrl+shift+i) it works great.

```
full = $.post('https://www.shufersal.co.il/_layouts/Shufersal_Pages/ajax.aspx',
{"AjaxCallAction":"AddProductToBasket","paramProductID":7296073231578,"paramQuantity":2,"paramRemarks":"","paramUM":""});

console.log(full.responseText); //required data
```

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEZd1.png) a screenshot of the response I get from the server console:
here.

But when I write this with the following script, I dont get the same result

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function run() {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setRequestInterception(true); //set the request option (triggered with goto)
    page.on('request', req => {
        //create data
        let prodID = 7296073231578; //shoko
        let qty = 2;
        let remarks='';
        let unitofmeasure = '';
        var request = {
            AjaxCallAction:"AddProductToBasket",
            paramProductID:prodID,
            paramQuantity:qty,
            paramRemarks:remarks,
            paramUM:unitofmeasure
        }

        var data = {
            'method': 'POST',
            'url': 'https://www.shufersal.co.il/_layouts/Shufersal_Pages/ajax.aspx', //just to make sure
            'postData': JSON.stringify(request)
        };
        req.continue(data);

    });

    const response = await page.goto('https://www.shufersal.co.il/_layouts/Shufersal_Pages/ajax.aspx');
    console.log(response.statusText());
    console.log(response.responseText);

    console.log('done');
}   
run();
```

I get the following result in the cmd:

```
OK
undefined
done
```

Also, if I try to post request using "request" of nodejs:
(using [answered question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js))
but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: try with : var data = {
            'dataType' : "json",
            'contentType': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               'method': 'POST',
               'url': 'https://www.shufersal.co.il/_layouts/Shufersal_Pages/ajax.aspx',
               'postData': JSON.stringify(request)
        };

Comment: @Amine Ramoul Hi, thanks for trying to help. I tried what you said, but it does the same (btw added 'https:www to' to the url, w/o it says the url is invalid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send the request body using `x-www-form-urlencoded` for example:

```
AjaxCallAction=AddProductToBasket&paramProductID=12345&....
```

modify the req body or create object to urlencoded converter. it is also required to set header `Content-Type` and capture the response from `response` event listener.

```
async function run() {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setRequestInterception(true); //set the request option (triggered with goto)
    page.on('request', req => {
        //create data
        let prodID = 7296073231578; //shoko
        let qty = 2;
        let remarks = '';
        let unitofmeasure = '';
        var request = {
            AjaxCallAction: "AddProductToBasket",
            paramProductID: prodID,
            paramQuantity: qty,
            paramRemarks: remarks,
            paramUM: unitofmeasure
        }
        // convert JSON to x-www-form-urlencoded
        let reqBody = Object.keys(request).map((k) => {
            return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(request[k])
        }).join('&');
        var data = {
            'method': 'POST',
            'url': 'https://www.shufersal.co.il/_layouts/Shufersal_Pages/ajax.aspx',
             // the custom headers
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            'postData': reqBody
        };
        req.continue(data);
    });
    // capture intercepted response
    page.on('response', async response => {
        console.log("Resource Type: "  + response.request().resourceType());
        console.log("Response Text: " + await response.text());
        console.log("==============");
    });

    const response = await page.goto('https://www.shufersal.co.il/_layouts/Shufersal_Pages/ajax.aspx');
    // only capture default response
    //console.log(response.statusText());
    //console.log(response.responseText);

    //console.log('done');

}

run();
```

Comment: does this method still work? For me, the data doesn't get passed through when I post data like this.

Comment: his code works perfectly. just need to add "const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');".